# Jquery cookie not expiring

Tags: jquery, cookies

Not sure why my cookie is not expiring - the code alerts but does not expire the cookie.

I want to be able to expire the v1st cookie when a user selects a radio button which sets the first value in my preferences cookie to either 'Y' or 'N', so when its 'N' the v1st cookie needs to expire

```
var my_cookie_value = $.cookie('preferences');
var autoTimer = null
var perfVal =  my_cookie_value.substring(0,1);


 $(function($) {
    if (my_cookie_value == null) { 
        $('#main a').click(function() {
            if($(this).attr("id") != "pB") {
            $.cookie('preferences', 'YYY', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: '.mydomain.com'}); 
            }
            });

         $('#pB').click(function() {
         $.cookie('preferences', 'YYN', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: '.mydomain.com'});
         });

//expiring cookies
        var perfVal =  my_cookie_value.substring(0,1);
          if (perfVal == "N") {
          $.cookie('v1st', null, {path: '/', domain: '.mydomain.com'});
         //alert('delete v1st');
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: to delete a cookie set it like this : $.cookie("v1st", "any_value", { expires: -1 });

Answer (score 0):

try doing like:

```
$.cookie('v1st', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly delete the cookie if its of no more use:

Code to Delete cookie:

```
// returns false => No cookie found
// returns true  => A cookie was found
$.removeCookie('the_cookie'[, options]);
```

Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie, unless you're relying on the default options that is.

Answer (score 0):

All the above do work, but i have just discovered that the cookie i was trying to delete is being reset by the webserver as soon as it expires.